# Infinite loop occur when reading from file in c++

Tags: c++

```
#define SIZE 30

 // some code
ifstream outFile;   
outFile.open("lab.txt");   // opening lab document which has a sentence
char buffer[SIZE];         // buffer for storing the sentence when reading from file

while (!outFile.eof())     // reads lab.txt until eof
{   
    // two methods for output to screen which print sentence on debugging
    // but program doesn't terminate 
    outFile >> buffer;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    // outFile.getline(buffer, SIZE);
    // cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

this code is for reading from a sequence file, for example `lab.txt`. The problem is that, when i run the sentence in the file, i gets printed but is followed by an infinite loop which keeps on printing spaces, so the program never terminates. I've tried both ways but both result is the same. 
Any help would be welcomed?

Comment: Don't use `.eof()`

Comment: @Rakete1111 now it doesnt print anything.

Comment: What did you use then? You should loop over the return value of `operator<<`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line

Comment: Just a thing to bring up as it confused the heck out of me.  You are reading a file but you name the stream `outFile`.  The name of the variable is totaly inconsistent with it's use.  I would suggest something like `fin`(**f**ile **in**) or `infile` for input file streams.

Comment: Yes, it is rather confusing. But our lecture had it his way. Thank you for suggesting. it will definitely improve my code. @NathanOliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of reading from file is as follows:

```
while(outFile >> buffer) {
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Using `outFile.eof()` as condition is problematic.

Comment: @F.T. Then upvote and accept.

Comment: @F.T. Note that this does not alone let you discern between errors and reaching a successful end of file.  To have a complete understanding of the issues, I suggest reading something like ["dealing correctly with badbit, failbit, eofbit, and perror()"](https://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/).

Comment: Note: `outFile >> buffer` will gleefully overflow `buffer` if the stream contains a sequence that runs for 30 or more characters without whitespace. This applies to the initial question code as well. Consider using `std::string` rather than a `char` array for `buffer`.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree with you and I would suggest using `std::string buffer;` instead of `char buffer[SIZE];`

Comment: the char array was the demand of the task although doing it in string is easy.
thank you for your help though. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
while(outFile.getline(buffer, SIZE))
{
    .....
}
```

instead of `outFile.eof()`

Comment: Right idea, but why `getline`?

Comment: firstly overloaded operator >> will not accept the leading spaces so it is better to use getline. second getline handles the buffer overflow problem. It would be much better if we use std::string line; here and check while(getline(outfile,line))

Comment: The buffer overflow point is well taken, but this shifts the input to line-based from token based. When you change how the OP's code works, you should explain in the answer why you made the change and how your solution is better.